# How to fetch particular column from database using ajax in django

Tags: django, ajax

Here is my views.py

```
def contact(request):
    number= listing_model.objects.only('phone')
    data=serializers.serialize('json', number)
    return JsonResponse( data, safe=False )
```

I am getting output

"[{"model": "listings.listing_model", "pk": 2, "fields": {"title": "PG1", "address": "XYZ", "city": "Hyderabad", "state": "Telangana", "price": 4000, "pincode": 789654, "sqfoot": 300, "rooms": 3, "image": "images/th_SHFuSrw.jpg", "phone": 456789123}}, {"model": "listings.listing_model", "pk": 3, "fields": {"title": "PG2", "address": "DEF", "city": "TVM", "state": "KERELA", "price": 6000, "pincode": 456963, "sqfoot": 300, "rooms": 1, "image": "images/th.jpg", "phone": 123456789}}]"

I don't want all these fields I just want to display phone field. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[only()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#only) is just performance optimization, your serializer will still use all of the fields as you didn't set fields argument

From django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/serialization/#subset-of-fields)

> If you only want a subset of fields to be serialized, you can specify
> a fields argument to the serializer:
>
> ```
> from django.core import serializers data = serializers.serialize('xml', SomeModel.objects.all(), fields=('name','size'))
> ```

So in your case something in a line:

```
data=serializers.serialize('json', number, fields('number',))
```